# Intel DAL (IPHelper) occupies port 80 preventing IIS to start

Tags: windows-11, iis, intel

Recently I started to face a problem with Intel DAL.

I am developing webistes and usually my IIS started on system startup and begin to serve sites as expected.

Recently the sites did not start and I started to investigate what is happening.
When I tried to start them manually, I got the following error:

> The process cannot access the file because it is beeing used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020)

[image]

Then I checked which process occupied the ports wiht `netstat -aob`:
[image]

When I stopped this IPHelper service, I got a notification that another service is depending on that one:
[image]

Is it safe to disable Intel DAL (Dynamic Application Loader Host Interface Service) completely? I don't see any DAL settings in any of the Intel control panel software installed.

Can I somehow just disallow IPHelper to occupy ports 80 and 443?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/a/1729731/399064